# Looking to generate Win/Loss/Draw from Game Data in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

So I have been building a historical site for a sport and I am trying to figure out how I can generate wins/losses/draws to build a ladder from the game data using MongoDB.

All the seasons games are in the collection so I only want to combined "played" games and be able to select which round. Eg. If I get the games for Round 3 I was all the results summed from Rounds 1, 2 & 3. Etc.

Here is the sample game document.

```
{  
    "_id": ObjectId("99292162dd4b0838a6c4069f"),
    "id": 9719,
    "round": {  
        "number": 1,
        "name": "Round 1"
    },
    "date": "2014-3-22T14:5:00+08:00",
    "venue": {  
        "id": 2,
        "name": "My Oval"
    },
    "teams": [
        {  
            "type": "home",
            "club": ObjectId("55292162dd4b0849a6c4059f"),
            "stats": {  
                "players": [],
                "team": { }
            },
            "score": {
                "half": 10,
                "fulltime": 18
            },
            "winner": true
        },
        {  
            "type": "away",
            "club": ObjectId("66292162dd4b0123a6c9876f"),
            "stats": {  
                "players": [],
                "team": { }
            },
            "score": {
                "half": 12,
                "fulltime": 16
            },
            "winner": false
        }
    ],
    "winner": {
        "type": "home",
        "margin": 2
    },
    "played": true
}
```

This is where I have got to but have no idea where to go from there as I am fairly new to MongoDB.

```
db.games.aggregate([
    { "$match" : {"round.number" : 2, "played": true } },
    { $unwind : "$teams" } 
]);
```

If I need to make some changes to the Schema to make this work I am open to suggestions.

Appreciate your help.

**Edit: Expected Result**

As a minimum I was looking to get the following for each club.

```
{
    "club":      ObjectId,
    "club_name": String,
    "wins":      Number,
    "losses":    Number,
    "draws":     Number
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the expected result?

Comment: I have added that to the question. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the update, however the sample game document you provided is invalid.

Comment: Sorry about that. It is now valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following aggregation pipeline will at least give you the club id, number of losses, wins and draws. Note: to get the aggregated results for a round other than the first one, you can change your **`$match`** query to filter documents, returning all documents from the previous rounds like `$match: { "round.number": {$lte: 3}}`.

```
db.games.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "round.number": 1,
            "played": true
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$teams"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            teams: 1,
            win: {
                $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$teams.winner", true ] }, 1, 0 ]
            },
            lose: {
                $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$teams.winner", false ] }, 1, 0 ]
            },            
            draw: {
                $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$winner.type", "draw" ] }, 1, 0 ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$teams.club",            
            "wins": { $sum: "$win" },
            "losses": { $sum: "$lose" },
            "draws": { $sum: "$draw" },  
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            "club": "$_id",
            wins: 1,
            losses: 1,
            draws: 1
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "wins" : 0,
            "losses" : 1,
            "draws" : 0,
            "club" : ObjectId("66292162dd4b0123a6c9876f")
        }, 
        {
            "wins" : 1,
            "losses" : 0,
            "draws" : 0,
            "club" : ObjectId("55292162dd4b0849a6c4059f")
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

To get the final result with the club name field included, use the above aggregation cursor, iterate over the club collection using the club ID in the query, something like:

```
db.games.aggregate([pipeline]).forEach(function (doc){
   var result = doc;
   var club_name = db.club.findOne({_id: doc.club}).name;
   result["club_name"] = club_name;
   console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for that. Makes perfect sense. With regards to the draw situation. The $winner.type value will equal "draw" if it is a draw. And you are right that the $teams.winner is meant to be a boolean.